# Using the auto_route and flutter_bloc libraries to navigate page not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-bloc

I trying to using the auto_route and flutter_bloc libraries to navigate page, but BlocListener is not triggered.

I'm using `print(SplashRoute == NavigationState.initial().routeType);` to check the trigger condition with BlocListener, it's return `true`.

However, the BlocListener still not triggered.

How do I fix my code problem :(? This is the sample code of my app. Thanks.

**main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const AppWidget());
}


class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final rootRouter = RootRouter();
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => NavigationCubit()..nav(SplashRoute),
          ),
          // ... Other blocProvider
        ],
        child: BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return MaterialApp.router(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: state.themeData,
              routerDelegate: rootRouter.delegate(),
              routeInformationParser: rootRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}

class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(SplashRoute == NavigationState.initial().routeType);     // <------ return ture

    return MultiBlocListener(
      listeners: [
        BlocListener<NavigationCubit, NavigationState>(     // <------ Not working here
          listenWhen: (p, c) => c.routeType is SplashRoute,
          listener: (context, state) {
            LoggerService.simple.i('NavigationCubit page listening!!');
            context.read<NavigationCubit>().nav(HomeRoute);
            context.pushRoute(const HomeRoute());
          },
          // ... Other blocListener
        ),
      ],
      child: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**navigation_state.dart**

```
part of 'navigation_cubit.dart';

@freezed
abstract class NavigationState with _$NavigationState {
  const factory NavigationState({
    required Type routeType,
  }) = _NavigationState;

  factory NavigationState.initial() => const NavigationState(
        routeType:  SplashRoute,
      );
}
```

**navigation_cubit.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

import '../../../presentation/routes/router.gr.dart';

part 'navigation_cubit.freezed.dart';
part 'navigation_state.dart';

class NavigationCubit extends Cubit<NavigationState> {
  NavigationCubit() : super(NavigationState.initial());

  void nav(Type routeType) {
    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        routeType: routeType,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I can interpret from your code. Either way it will not work as you had hoped.

My understanding from your question is that you are trying to navigate using the `BlocListener` on initial state, which doesn't work.

The reason is that `BlocListener` is not triggered on initial state as it is not a state **change**, but rather something that is defined by the bloc.

The second thing I see is that you call the `nav` method when providing the bloc, which is a good thing: `NavigationCubit()..nav(SplashRoute)`. However, it will set the same value for the parameter `routeType`, which will not trigger a state **change** as it is the same value. Meaning that the `BlocListener` will not be triggered.

Set `routeType` to something else initially, perhaps set it to null, so that your bloc can identify a state change, then your BlocListener will be triggered.

EDIT:

Also, `c.routeType is SplashRoute` doesn't seem right. try changing to `c.routeType == SplashRoute` in your `listenWhen` property, otherwise your function in the `listener` property will not trigger

Comment: Thank you for your answer first. Actually I have tried to set routeType to null, but my bloc still not triggered...It's so depressing for me...T_T

Comment: I've edited my answer. Check that.

Comment: I think you are right.
However, I even deleted `listenWhen` property, but still not trigger...